# how to define a delegate in UIView class

Tags: delegates, protocols, ios7.1

I have a `UIView` class and `UIViewController`class. I want to do after finish some task in the  `UIView` class need to call a method in `UIViewController` class. So I did like this.

In my ViewClass

`

```
#import "IntroView.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"



@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate <NSObject>;

@required
- (void) processCompleted;
@end


@interface IntroControll : UIView<UIScrollViewDelegate> {


id <SampleProtocolDelegate> _delegate;
}



@property (nonatomic,strong) id delegate;

-(void)startSampleProcess; // Instance method
```

`

Then in My ViewController class

`

```
#import "IntroControll.h"




@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SampleProtocolDelegate>
{

IntroControll *delegate;

}
```

`

But it shows an error in `@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SampleProtocolDelegate>`

"Cannot find protocal declaration for 'SampleProtocolDelegate'"

Why is that and How can I solve this problem.

Please help me
Thank you

Comment: In which file is your protocol declared? Is it in IntroControll.h? Remove the Semi Colon after the protocol declaration.

Comment: Yes its in IntroController.h. It is a View class

Comment: I tryed that but same errors coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes because you are importing FirstViewController.h in IntroControll.h. And then you have done the protocol declaration.

Hence the FirstViewController.h is processed first, and it is unable to find the protocol declaration since ImtroControll.h is not processed yet.

Remove the import of FirstViewController.h from IntoControll.h, if it is not needed. Else forward declare FirstViewController.

```
#import "IntroView.h"

@class FirstViewController;

@protocol SampleProtocolDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) processCompleted;
@end
```

Import FirstViewController.h in the IntroControll.m file.

Comment: Thanks that error was dissappeared.. But there is a error giving at IntroControll *delegate; line in the FirstViewController.h It says Unknown type name IntroControll. Why is that?

Comment: IntroControll.h is imported in FirstViewController.h ?

Comment: I create a variable inside FirstViewController.m file under Viewdidload method. Then that error eliminated. But still dont know why Its not allowed to do in .h file.

Comment: It is because, you are importing FirstViewController.h in INtroControll.h and vice versa.. The best way is ti forward declare the FIrstViewController in IntroControll.h and import FirstViewController in IntroControll.m.. This should solve. I have updated the answer accordingly